# Characterization of functions that have the data processing inequality

Tags: information-theory, mutual-information

I wonder if people have studied the characterization of data processing inequality. Here's the [data processing inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_processing_inequality) for mutual information: 3 variables for Markov chain: $X\to Y\to Z$, then $I(X, Y)\geq I(X, Z)$.

What are the other functions that have this property? I'm looking for characterization of function $f$ such that $f(X, Y)\geq f(X, Z)$.

Comment: I don't know if this characterises the data processing property, but certainly it's an extension: The DPI for mutual information follows from the DPI for KL-divergence. The generalisations of KL divergence to [$f$-divergences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-divergence) also satisfy the DPI property, and of course these induce mutual $f$-informations that satisfy the DPI property.

Comment: The data processing inequality also holds for the [$\alpha$-mutual information](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7308959)